# How to get automatic recommendation on PotgreSQL PgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I use SQL Server as main database and Postgresql as back up option. Whenever I work on SSMS, I get auto recommendation whether typing table name or column name. I have attached a picture below for better clarification.
[image: Automatic Recommended Pop-ups on SSMS]

However, I do not get such recommendations while using PgAdmin and it leads to chances of higher error rate. Should I need to enable any option to get such automatic recommendations like SSMS?
[image: No Automatic Recommendations on PgAdmin]

Comment: Tools like DataGrip and Navicat do support this, and many other things. For my daily work pgAdmin is too limited in its functionality.

Comment: Thank You @FrankHeikens.
So, is there no way to enable such functionality on PgAdmin??